# How to get the closing tag in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am dealing with pagination and would like my script to scrape a table, click on the next button, scrape the next table and click on next until it is no longer clickable.

The only difference in clickable vs non-clickable seems to be the `disabled>` closing tag.

My idea was to create a while loop and click on the button until the disabled tag disappears, but I'm not sure how to get that tag in the first place.

Even if the button is disabled, Selenium doesn't throw an "Element not interactable" error so I don't think I can go down that route.

```
airport_list = []
fees_list = []

airports = ["https://www.aopa.org/destinations/business/13035#fees", "https://www.aopa.org/destinations/business/35555#fees"]

for a in airports:
    driver.get(a)
    time.sleep(3)

    # Click dropdown
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "mat-select-arrow"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    # Select "All aircraft"
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class = "mat-option-text"]')[8].click()
    time.sleep(2)

    try:        

        # Check if fees are available
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//mat-row[@class = "mat-row ng-star-inserted"]')

        #Scrape each row
        fees_table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//mat-row[@class = "mat-row ng-star-inserted"]')
            for fee in fees_table:
            fees_list.append(fee.text)
            airport_list.append(a)

        #Click on "Next" button

        driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class = "mat-button-wrapper"]')[4].click()
        time.sleep(2)

    except:
        fees_list.append("This location has not disclosed fees or does not charge fees.")
        airport_list.append(a)           

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to extract the maximum number of items from the bottom of the table, divide that number by 10 and round up to the nearest number. I am then using that number to iterate through a range.

```
airport_list = []
fees_list = []

airports = ["https://www.aopa.org/destinations/business/13035#fees"]

for a in airports:
    driver.get(a)
    time.sleep(3)

    # Click dropdown
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "mat-select-arrow"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    # Select "All aircraft"
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class = "mat-option-text"]')[8].click()
    time.sleep(2)

    try:        
        # Check if fees are available
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//mat-row[@class = "mat-row ng-star-inserted"]')

        # Get number of items
        number_of_items = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "mat-paginator-range-label"]').text.split()[-1]
        #print(number_of_items)

        if float(number_of_items) >= 11:
            number_of_button_clicks = math.ceil(float(number_of_items)/10)
        else:
            number_of_button_clicks = 0
        #print(number_of_button_clicks)

        for click in range(0, number_of_button_clicks):
            #Scrape each row
            fees_table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//mat-row[@class = "mat-row ng-star-inserted"]')
            for fee in fees_table:
                fees_list.append(fee.text)
                airport_list.append(a)

            #Click on "Next" button

            driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class = "mat-button-wrapper"]')[4].click()
            time.sleep(2)

    except:
        fees_list.append("This location has not disclosed fees or does not charge fees.")
        airport_list.append(a)


#print(fee_list)
#print(airport_list)            

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going on next page use the max line limit as shown in below code. On top of that you really dont need to use try except block -

```
for a in airports:
    driver.get(a)
    time.sleep(3)

    # Click dropdown
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "mat-select-arrow"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    # Select "All aircraft"
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class = "mat-option-text"]')[8].click()
    time.sleep(3)

    # select 100 Items per page if items are present
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//mat-select[@aria-label='Items per page:']")) > 0 :
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//mat-select[@aria-label='Items per page:']").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='mat-option-text' and text()='100']/parent::mat-option").click()

    # Scrape each row
    fees_table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//mat-row[@class = "mat-row ng-star-inserted"]')
    for fee in fees_table:
        fees_list.append(fee.text)
    print(fees_list)

        # if needed then Click on "Next" button using this xpath and apply same for loop as above
        #driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//button[@aria-label='Next page']").click()
driver.close()
```

Comment: That won't really work because some tables contain more than 100 items.

Comment: I have given that too read the code ahead. you can click on next button using that locator and wrap your current for loop logic with other outer for loop in such way that it will work on subsequent pages